# ASP.NET MVC 3 and restful routing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 application. I am trying to implement the routing standard found at http://www.slideshare.net/calamitas/restful-best-practices. I'm using slides 15 and and 17 for reference. I understand that this slide deck is regarding RAILS. However, This syntax seems so much cleaner and more natural. That's why I want to use it.

I have successfully implemented the Index and Show actions in my controller. However, I am having problems getting the Create and Update actions to work. At this time, when I reference either of these, I receive a 404. Currently, my controller looks like this:

```
public class OrdersController : Controller
{
    // GET: /Orders/
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var results = new[] {
            new {id=1, price=1.23, quantity=2}
        };
        return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Orders/{orderID}
    public ActionResult Show(int id)
    {
        string result = "order:" + id;
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    //
    // POST: /Orders/{order}
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(object order)
    {
        var message = "The order was successfully created!";
        return Json(message);
    }

    //
    // PUT: /Orders/{orderID}
    [HttpPut]
    public ActionResult Update(object orderID)
    {
        var message = "The order was successfully updated!";
        return Json(message);
    }
}
```

When I register my routes, I use the following:

```
context.MapRoute(
    "OrderList",
    "Orders",
    new { action = "Index", controller="Orders" }
);

context.MapRoute(
    "Order",
    "Orders/{id}",
    new { action = "Show", controller = "Orders", id="" }
);

context.MapRoute(
    "InsertOrder",
    "Orders",
    new { action = "Create", controller = "Orders" }
);

context.MapRoute(
    "UpdateOrder",
    "Orders/{orderID}",
    new { action = "Update", controller = "Orders", orderID = "" }
);
```

I'm attempting to CREATE and UPDATE via JQuery. When I'm using the following:

```
// Update
var order = getOrder();
$.ajax({
    url: "/orders",
    type: "put",
    data: JSON.stringify(order),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("There was a problem.");
    }
});


// Create
var order = getOrder();
$.ajax({
    url: "/orders",
    type: "post",
    data: JSON.stringify(order),
    contentType: "application/json",
    success: function (result) {
        alert(result);
    },
    error: function () {
        alert("There was a problem.");
    }
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Because its a 404, I tend to believe that it is an incorrect routing. I think there may be a conflict, but I don't know how to prove or correct this. At the same time, I'm not sure that I'm setting the data property correctly in my jQuery. Thank you for any help that can be provided.

Comment: why two of your routes have the same url?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your URL is missing the action for create.  Change the URL to the following:

```
$.ajax({ 
    url: "/orders/create", 
    ....
```

The reason is that your routing never reach the second one defined for Orders.  All url's starting with Orders will go to the Order controller and Index action.

```
context.MapRoute( 
    "OrderList", 
    "Orders", 
    new { action = "Index", controller="Orders" } 
);
```

EDIT:

You should use a general routing in this case:

```
context.MapRoute( 
    "Order", 
    "Orders/{action}/{id}", 
    new { action = "Index", controller = "Orders", id="" } 
);
```

If the URL is '/Orders' then it will go to 'Index', but '/Orders/Create' will go to the 'Create' action in the controller.

Comment: But in the URL I included it stated that a url like "/Orders/Create" would not be RESTful. Rather, the primary difference is in the Http Verb that's used. Am I way off base? Or, is is approach something that ASP.NET MVC can't do?

Comment: You would have to name all of your methods "Index" and have different overloads OR you would need to have one method called Index and inside of the method, do different logic based on the verb.

Answer (score 2):

I think you only need the next MapRoutes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "OrdersIndex", // Route name
    "{controller}", // URL with parameters
    new {
            controller = "Orders", 
            action = "Index" 
        } // Parameter defaults
);
routes.MapRoute(
    "OrdersCrud", // Route name
    "{controller}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { 
            controller = "Orders", 
            action = "Crud"
        } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Then in your controller class you would need something like this:

```
public class OrdersController : Controller
{
    // GET: /Orders/
    [HttpGet] //GET is by default
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var results = new[] {
            new {id=1, price=1.23, quantity=2}
        };
        return Json(results, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    //
    // POST: /Orders/
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(object order)
    {   //Create
        var message = "The order was successfully created!";
        return Json(message);
    }

    //
    // GET: /Orders/{orderID} 
    [HttpGet]//GET is by default
    public ActionResult Crud(int id)
    {   //Show
        string result = "order:" + id;
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }

    //
    // PUT: /Orders/{orderID}
    [HttpPut]
    public ActionResult Crud(object orderWithIDProperty)
    {   //Update
        var message = "The order was successfully updated!";
        return Json(message);
    }

    //
    // DELETE: /Orders/{orderID}
    [HttpDelete]
    public ActionResult Crud(int id)
    {   //Delete
        var message = "The order was successfully deleted!";
        return Json(message);
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to specify explicitly the `[HttpGet]` attribute as are explained in this [link](http://rachelappel.com/asp.net-mvc-actionresults-explained).

Comment: This is on the right track, but not quite there yet.  When you post, you are posting to the list, not a particular id, which is the only way to hit the Crud action.  So you need to change the crud action to have the name index.  Also when you're trying to work in a CRUD environment, you need to specify the allowed http methods for each action.

Comment: @NickLarsen you're right. I updated my answer putting a `HttpPost` index (I can overload the actionresult with an input parameter) a `HttpDelete`.